# ActionScript 3.0 loading an external image into a container movieclip?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, filereference, addchild

I am new to AS3 and I need some help with the Senocular Transform Tool (AS3 version)

I'm having trouble with loading in an external image such that I can transform with the Senocular Transform Tool class.

I have managed to load in the picture but the transform class doesn't seem want to grab it.

```
var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();
MovieClip(root).loadBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openClick);

function openClick(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    fileRef.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectHandler);
    fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
    var fileFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Images","*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png");
    fileRef.browse([fileFilter]);
}

function selectHandler(event:Event):void {
    fileRef.load();
}

function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
    var image:Loader = new Loader();
    var imgSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
    image.loadBytes(fileRef.data);
    imgSprite.addChild(image);
    addChild(imgSprite);
    imgSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, select);
    imgSprite.x=200;
    imgSprite.y=200;
}
```

I'm trying to load the image from my HD into a loader, then a sprite, then an empty container movieClip on the stage...

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try add `image.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoaded)` to see if it loaded successfully. Also, if you set width or height of image (even indirectly through parent) before it loaded, it will be lost due to transformation matrix f@&k-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should wait for [LOADER](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html) to load complete byte before adding 
them to sprite, because huge file takes time to load in App,

like that

```
var image:Loader = new Loader();
image.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageloaded);
image.loadBytes(fileRef.data);
```

and event handler as

```
private function imageloaded(event:Event):void
{
    var image:Loader = event.currentTarget.loader as Loader;
    var imgSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
        imgSprite.addChild(image);
        addChild(imgSprite);
}
```

you may also used its Fault handler to manage faults

Hopes that helps